# How to construct a Joomla! query for matching two field values in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla, select-query

i have a table #__newtoys_variants having many fields of which id and v_prod_id are there.

Now although id is unique - the v_prod_id is product id 
The url displays product information and price

```
example.com/index.php?option=com_newtoys&id=2&vid=7
```

here id value is extracted from id and vid is v_prod_id as extracted from db table row against the corresponding

Here is a brief of table for instance

```
id v_prod_id v_price
1     7       200
2     7       220
3     1       250
4     1       270
5     2       300
6     10      350
7     9       220
8     7       195
```

Now i intend that 404 error / 500 error / page does not exist should be displayed in front end - if the id and v_prod_id is not matched in front end url

In case a user changes url to say

```
example.com/index.php?option=com_newtoys&id=2&vid=1
```

then want 404 error / 500 error / page does not exist to be displayed in front end
Here is Table Database 
[image]
Can any one help on it to achieve same

Here is a brief function - unsure what exactly should be in sql query or function so that id & v_prod_id should be matched as in array and in case result is zero then error message can be displayed

```
function loadProduct($id ,$vid){
    $mainframe =JFactory::getApplication();
    $option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
    $db =JFactory::getDBO();
    global $Itemid; 
    $sql = "";

    $db->setQuery($sql);

if ($rows = $db->loadObjectlist()) {
return $rows[0];

} else {
  if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
    JError::raiseError(500, "Something went horribly wrong, the query returned the error ". $db->getErrorMsg());

  } else {
 JError::raiseError(404, "404, Page does not Exists ". $db->getErrorMsg());
  }
}       
    }
```

can any one help and suggest. Bounty added

Comment: Guides to do the error.
 You need check whether the vid=7 value is matched in database(Code sql query to retrieve whether it matches), if not matched you need to show the error.. thats all

Comment: Yes - i understand that sql query needs to be written to check whether v_prod_id matches with corresponding id field. If not then error function as mentioned above. But am naive in sql queries - so if can assist on same. thanks

Comment: Sorry, Ruchika i dont understood. you mean do i wanna write the code for checking the prod_id?

Comment: i know its not a forum to ask to write code, but yes if can assist to help on same to provide sql query so as to achieve the desired

Comment: For me its not a Problem i can re write or code something :) So let me give you a answer in php pdo to query sql to check the vproid matches to the corresponding id or should you wanna show the error? or just ignore?

Comment: you can post answer if able to work out

Comment: Hi , Do you use sessions in your code in some where ???

Comment: Although cache enabled but Session is not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function loadProduct($id, $vid){
  $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
  $option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
  $db = JFactory::getDBO();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query->select('id, v_prod_id');
  $query->from($db->quoteName('#__newtoys_variants'));
  $query->where($db->quoteName('id')." = ".$db->quote($id), 'AND');
  $query->where($db->quoteName('v_prod_id')." = ".$db->quote($vid));
  $db->setQuery($sql);

  if ($rows = $db->loadObjectlist()) {
    return $rows[0];
  } else {
    if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
      JError::raiseError(500,
       "Something went horribly wrong, the query returned the error ". $db->getErrorMsg());
    } else {
      JError::raiseError(404,
       "404, Page does not Exists ". $db->getErrorMsg());
    }
  }
}
```

See here for further details:

https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

**UPDATE**

You asked in the comments for a Joomla! translation of the following query:

```
Select *, (select prod_name from #__newtoy_products where id=v.id) as prod_name
from #__newtoys_variants AS v Where v.state='1' and v.id = '".$v_prod_id."'
```

...which is basically the same as this:

```
SELECT v.*, p.prod_name
FROM #__newtoys_variants AS v
LEFT JOIN #__newtoy_products AS p
ON p.id = v.id
WHERE v.state='1' and v.id = '".$v_prod_id"'
```

...which should map to something like this in Joomla!:

```
$query->select(array('v.*', 'p.prod_name'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__newtoys_variants', 'v'))
      ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__newtoy_products', 'p'))
      . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('p.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('v.id') . ')')
      ->where($db->quoteName('v.state')." = ".$db->quote(1), 'AND')
      ->where($db->quoteName('v.id')." = ".$db->quote($v_prod_id));
```

Comment: Great - i think its almost close, just need some more if to merge above query with this `"Select *, (select prod_name from #__newtoy_products where id=v.id) as prod_name 
     from #__newtoys_variants AS v Where v.state='1' and v.id = '".$v_prod_id."'"`    . How to rewrite query as single merged query. It will help in achieving the desired as what looking for

Comment: Thanks - its showing now `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'v' on  this line     ->where($db->quoteName('v.state')." = ".$db->quote(1), 'AND')` . Also once this parse error issue resolved can i simply join in both the new query and old query

Comment: Well I did say "something like this" - was hoping that would be enough to point you in the right direction without a step by step troubleshoot as this would probably be easier for you than me given I don't have Joomla! installed locally... Could maybe ask a separate SO question if the documentation isn't sufficient? The join syntax is described here: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Selecting_Records_from_Multiple_Tables

Comment: i understand that . You have pointed me in right direction, just a last pointer - why is id coming as unambiguous - `Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous SQL=SELECT id, v_prod_id,v.*,p.prod_name FROM `#__new#__variants`,`#__new#__variants` AS `v` LEFT JOIN `#__new#__products` AS `p` ON (`p`.`id` = `v`.`v_prod_id`) WHERE `id` = '188' AND `v_prod_id` = '12' AND `v`.`state` = '1' AND `v`.`id` = '188'`. What code should i rectify

Comment: am able to solve after using table alias. Thanks - your solution worked perfectly and much thanks for pointing in right direction - it really helped me in learning same too

Comment: No problem, glad you worked it out and feel free to edit my answer if a correction is needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Example Code to check the v_prod_id Matches**

```
<?php
//connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
if(isset($_GET['id']) && ($_GET['vid'])){
//sanitize the id and vid i didnt sanitized
$id = $_GET['id'];
$vid = $_GET['vid'];
//Coded by Ajmal PraveeN
                                        $sqlq = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, v_prod_id FROM __newtoys_variants WHERE id= :id");
                                        $sqlq->bindValue(':id', $id);
                                        $sqlq->execute();
                                        $row = $sqlq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//if you want to check the id whether it matches? remove the comment line and check the id matches
if(/*($id !== $row['id']) && */($vid !== $row['v_prod_id'])){
echo 'v prod id error';
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry doesnt work bind function error then execute error and then fetch error.

Comment: Could you please give me the screenshots of errors? I was Given you a example code to check the db prod match from get, you need to implement to your main script as you need. Does your server has pdo driver? if not install it